# using pybind11 to use c++ in python, running into issues compiling pybind11 headers

Tags: c++, compilation, pybind11

It appears that I am having issues compiling the header libraries in pybind11.

I have three files, pyBind.cpp, pythonFunctionBind.hpp, and pythonFunctionBind.cpp.  I tried compiling on a linux machine and it actually worked (C++ code, python module, the whole shebang), but the python module I need has to interface with a windows program so I'm trying to compile on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.  The code is as follows:

```
// pyBind.cpp
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pythonFunctionBind.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;
PYBIND11_MODULE(pybindTest,m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind test but i don't know where to put my project";
    m.def("A",&returnAP,"return 3");
    m.def("B",&returnBP,"return 4");
}
```

```
// pythonFunctionBind.hpp
#ifndef pythonBind_hpp
#define pythonBind_hpp

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        int i;
        int j;
        void write();
        void print();
        int returnP();
        std::vector<int> s;
    protected:
        int p;
        void writeI();
        void writeJ();
        virtual void writeP();
};

class B: public A {
   protected:
        void writeP() override;
};

int returnAP();
int returnBP();

#endif
```

```
// pythonFunctionBind.cpp
#include "pythonFunctionBind.hpp"

void A::write() {
    writeI();
    writeJ();
    writeP();
}

void A::print() {
    std::cout << i << j << p << "\n";
}

int A::returnP() {
    return p;
}

void A::writeI() {
    i = 1;
}

void A::writeJ() {
    j = 2;
}

void A::writeP() {
    p = 3;
}

void B::writeP() {
    p = 4;
}

int returnAP() {
    A a;
    a.write();
    int p = a.returnP();
    return p;
}

int returnBP() {
    B b;
    b.write();
    int p = b.returnP();
    return p;
}
```

I have been following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/hr0HWX1b1d0) to try and get it to compile but with no luck.  When I use the command like the tutorial in my MINGW64 environment:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fpermissive -shared -fPIC -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -I./include/ -I./pybind11/include/ `python -m pybind11 --includes` pyBind.cpp pythonFunctionBind.cpp -o pybindTest.pyd `python-config --ldflags` -lmingw32 -mwindows -L libwinpthread-1.dll
```

I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from pybind11/detail/../detail/Python.h:63,
                 from pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h:266,
                 from pybind11/detail/../attr.h:13,
                 from pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                 from pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                 from pyBind.cpp:2:
pybind11/detail/../detail/cpython/fileutils.h:17:12: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-f
permissive]
   17 | PyAPI_FUNC(_Py_error_handler); _Py_GetErrorHandler(const char *errors);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pybind11/detail/../detail/pyport.h:683:77: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
  683 | #                               define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) Py_IMPORTED_SYMBOL RTYPE
      |                                                                             ^~~~~
In file included from pybind11/detail/../detail/fileutils.h:23,
                 from pybind11/detail/../detail/Python.h:159:
pybind11/detail/../detail/cpython/fileutils.h:17:71: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type c
onversion before ';' token
   17 | PyAPI_FUNC(_Py_error_handler); _Py_GetErrorHandler(const char *errors);
      |
```

I doubt the issue is with cpython but I don't know what is going on here.  I really didn't expect the included libraries to give me trouble while compiling so I am really at a loss.  Do i just go storming in and try and edit the fileutils.h, hoping something will work?  Cuz I really don't know what I'm doing.

I've tried googling and didn't find what I was looking for.  Any help is appreciated, whether it be insight into this problem, a better alternative to pybind11, or a straightforward/detailed guide to cross compiling from linux to windows (i did try looking this up but I wasn't able to follow what I was supposed to do, so with that one I'm at a loss too).  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the heads up, editing post now.  While you're here, do you know much about compiling for Pybind11?

Comment: Afraid not. There has to be someone around here who does, though.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you run the compile command in cmd? My windows cmd console cannot even replace `python -m pybind11 --includes` with the include paths. Also, my windows has no `python-config --ldflags`. Have you encountered these problems?

Comment: I managed to compile your example on my windows system...still not sure how your error shows up though. A wild guess is your pybind11 has a wrong version. Try reinstalling pybind11 perhaps?